# How to uninstall Plugins in IntelliJ IDEA?

Tags: intellij-idea

Others have written to simply right-click the plugin to install, and then "Uninstall" will show up. But for me, right-clicking does nothing.

I am using Linux if that makes a difference. Thanks.
[image: a screenshot of IDEA's Plugins window]

Answer (score 46, accepted):

Try the `Installed` tab instead of the `Marketplace`.

Here's the official tutorial: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/managing-plugins.html#remove-plugin

> 1. In the Settings/Preferences dialog ⌘,, select Plugins.
> 2. Open the Installed tab and find the plugin that you want to remove.
> 3. Click The down arrow next to the Disable/Enable button and select Uninstall from the dropdown menu.

Comment: thank you! that's pretty bad design that it doesn't show the uninstall button right in the marketplace tab

Comment: Thanks! These instructions still worked for me on Windows 10, Pycharm version 2020.3.3.

Comment: Also, you must disable the plugin to uninstall it.

Comment: I was able to uninstall one plugin with this method, then nothing. I have 121 plugins that can not be uninstalled. The only option I have is "Enable for All Projects"

Comment: @Kr1 Are they bundled plugins? If so, they can't be uninstalled, only disabled!

Answer (score 1):

Go to **File**, **Settings**, **Plugins**, **Installed**, right click on the plugin, **Uninstall** or disable in case the plugin cannot be uninstalled directly on IntelliJ.

Answer (score 0):

In MACOS 14.2.1 (23C71),  if you want to remove plugins from the terminal itself.

1. go to `~/Library/Application Support/JetBrains/PyCharm2023.1/plugins`, add your pycharm version here
2. use `rm -rf <plugin name>` to delete plugin or use `rm -rf *` to delete all plugins